# How to model the dataset for a IR image stream

Tags: dataframe, image, stream, cloud, parquet

I have a IR image stream, each frame has a 640x480 resolution and uses 16bit to store the actual raw data in each pixel. I have never worked with images nor IR images. What I want to do is to think about how to save this stream of images into a file to save it on the Cloud.

Are there best practices?

Should I think about storing the images onto a structured dataframe file like parquet? E.g. the first columns the flattened encoded raw data, and the other columns the metadata of the image? Each row would be an image, and I could partition the parquet files using the datetime as index. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.